# How to find element of parent and store in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Can you please tell me how to How to separate  parent and child node in an different  array?

I have three parent nodes: `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`

- `"a"` parent node has these children: `"a_1"`, `"a_2"`, `"a_3"`, ... and so on
- `"b"` parent node has these children: `"b_1"`, `"b_2"`, `"b_3"`, ... and so on
- `"c"` parent node has these children: `"c_1"`, `"c_2"`, `"c_3"`, ... and so on

Now. `"a-1"` parent node has also child like that: `"a_1_1"`, `"a_1_2"`, `"a_1_3"`. The same for `"b_1"`, `"b_2"`, ... Every node has children.

http://jsfiddle.net/v34bh/1/

```
var arr=["a_1","c_3"];
var parent="a"

console.log(sortArray(parent,arr))
function sortArray(parent,arry){
    var a=new Array();
    for (var i=0;i<arry.length;i++){
        if(arry[i].indexOf('a')!=-1){
           a.push(arr[i]) 
        }
    }
    return a;

}
```

I am getting correct result when array is simple. As it want child of `"a"` expected output is `"a_1"`.

My logic fail when array is `["a_1","a_a_1","c_3"]`.
Expected output is `["a_1"]` because I need child of `"a"`. But it is coming `["a_1","a_1_1"]`.

Secondly my logic fail when result id not sortable:
When the array is `["a_2","a_1","c_3"]`.
Output come `["a_2","a_1"]`.
Expected output `["a_1","a_2"]`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*separate in an different array*"? Do you want to "find direct children of a given parent id in an array"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it well, you can use

```
function sortArray(parent,arry){
    var a = new Array();
    for (var i=0; i<arry.length; i++) {
        var pos = arry[i].lastIndexOf('_');
        if (arry[i].substring(0,pos) == parent)
           a.push(arry[i]);
    }
    return a.sort();    
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/v34bh/4/)

Alternatively, with regular expressions and ES5 array methods:

```
function sortArray(parent,arry){
    var rg = new RegExp('^'+parent+'_\\d+$');
    return arry.filter(function(i){
        return rg.test(i);
    }).sort();
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/v34bh/5/)

If you want to add remaining items at the beginning,

```
function sortArray(parent,arry){
    var arrs = [ [], [] ];
    for (var i=0;i<arry.length;i++){
        var pos = arry[i].lastIndexOf('_'),
            cond = arry[i].substring(0,pos) == parent;
        arrs[+cond].push(arry[i]);
    }
    return arrs[0].concat(arrs[1].sort());    
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/v34bh/6/)

Comment: @orial your 50% awswe is correct but it is not sorted wat

Comment: Answer is 0: "a_1" 1: "a_3" 2: "a_2"..Expected is "a_1", "a_2","a_3"

Comment: @user3530755 If you want to sort, then just add `.sort()`.

Comment: THANKS FOR HELP .one more help can we add remaining element in starting of array

Comment: [a_1,a_2,a_3] Till now this the out put .can we add a_2_3,c_3 in starting in any oder .Experted output is [a_2_3,c_3,a_1,a_2,a_3] or[c_3,a_2_3,a_1,a_2,a_3]

Comment: @orial  is it possible last Question